# How does Tensorflow know cuda version?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an old desktop that I'm trying to use Tensorflow on after a hiatus. I uninstalled previous versions of Cuda and installed 11.3. When I try to use Tensorflow and check the Cuda package versions, I get 11.2 which is an old one.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2021-06-25 18:02:37.515683: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-06-25 18:02:37.515712: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
>>> sys_details = tf.sysconfig.get_build_info()
>>> sys_details["cuda_version"]
'11.2'
```

How does Tensorflow lookup what the Cuda version should be? Where could these old version remnants be hanging around?

Edit 1:

One more thing: `nvcc --version` returns the correct version.

Comment: "get_build_info" should be a big hint....

Comment: @talonmies, "get_build_info" does not provide any additional information regarding environment variables how it looks things up.

Comment: It doesn't look things up -- that is the point. The CUDA version dependencies are **built in** to Tensorflow when the code was written and when it was built. You can't change it. "get_build_info" , with emphasis on the second word in that API's name. You *must* have installed the version which Tensorflow was built against. No other version will work

Comment: Aha. I didn't know that part. Make your response an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

try use this command

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-11.3
```

Comment: Tried it and it did not work. Got any other ideas?

Comment: Try: # CUDA 11.3:, it need to be the path your cuda is
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.3/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.3/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: @Zichzheng: Sorry, but all of this is wrong. Tensorflow has hardcoded CUDA library versions dependencies and you can't change them via environment variables. You can only use environment setting to  allow Tensorflow to *find* the version it expects, not *change* the version it expects

Comment: I though I can use CUDA_HOME to switch version, if so, will uninstall the old version work?